# Magento - Updating attribute IF THE OPTION changed

Tags: magento

I really need some support regarding magento:

on this page: https://goo.gl/wTeUtG

If the option changed out of the dropdown, like from 150 Gramm to 200 Gramm, the ingredients (on this page as "Zutaten") also should be updated. But only the price is going to change not the text right into tooltip on "Zutaten".

How or where can I do this?

That's what I have tried so far:

I've created a new attribute and put it into the checkbox.phtml. This is the code for it:

```
<p>
<label>Zutaten:</label>
<a class="tooltips" href="#">
<img src="https://shop.ellyseidl.de/skin/frontend/base/default/pektsekye/optionbundle‌​/info_icon.gif" width="11px" height="11px" />
<span><strong>Zutaten:</strong> 
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_selection->getId())->getData('zutaten'‌​); ?>
</span>
</a>
</p>
```

But it doesn't change the tooltip once a option is selected

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will have to do it manually with jQuery since you are using it on your page, by adding event on change on the select box with the **id="attribute154"** or the **class="super-attribute-select"**.
You will have to change the text in the tooltip according to the option being selected.

**EDIT:**

`jQuery('#attribute154').on('change', function() {
  var selectedVal = jQuery(this).val();
 //If you want to change the tooltip according to the selected text this is how you can get it:
 var selectedText = jQuery(this).find("option:selected").text();
  if (selectedVal != '') {
    var ingredientsText = '';
    if (selectedText == '150 Gramm') {
        ingredientsText = 'Ingredients for 150 Gramm';
    } else if (selectedText == '200 Gramm') {
        ingredientsText = 'Ingredients for 200 Gramm';
    }
    //And so on
    jQuery('.tooltips').find('span:first').html('Zutaten:'+' Folgen in Kürze: '+ingredientsText);
  } else {
     jQuery('.tooltips').find('span:first').html('Zutaten:'+' Folgen in Kürze: ');
  }
});`

Please have in mind that you must change the text the way you need it. I still don't know what you have to add in the tooltip, but I just tested this on your site and it works. According to the text Folgen in Kürze which means coming soon, not sure what is the text you need to update.
EDIT2: 
The ingredientsText var will depend on the quantity of Gramm selected, if they are static you can enter them in the code by yourself, if they are dynamic, you will have to add them somewhere in the HTML in a hidden <div> for example and then fetch them with JS from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help zokibtmkd, but where do I've to put this script into? And how can i execute it?

Comment: You have to put it in the template where the select boxes are being printed. In Magento 1.9.1.0 this template is located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml unless you are using own theme and template for this. Place the JS code at the bottom and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi zokibtmkd, I just paste the script where you told me, but it seems that it doesn't work. Do you have to adjust anything else?

Comment: I have updated the script, this one will change the text in the tooltip, but as I said I am not sure what you are intending to do with it. What should happen if I select 150 Gramm for example, what is the text that needs to be added in the tooltip?

Comment: Let me try to explain this: As every product you can select in the Options "150 Gramm", "200 Gramm", etc. has his own "Zutaten" -> Ingredients, the tooltip also have to updated, as they are related to the product itself. For example: "150 Gramm" has other ingredients than "200 Gramm" - thats why the tooltip has to be updated.

The "Zutaten" are saved in an another attribute called "zutaten". 

Does that work, with the script you have shown me?

Comment: No it won't work, but to make it work you will have to provide the JS code with the text (ingredients) for each selected option. I will update my answer again.

Comment: I didn't modified any JS code so far, the only part which I've changed is the code you can find on my very first question. On single products it works fine as you can see here: https://goo.gl/3egdS3

Which code do I've to provide you?

Comment: I just tested it and it really works fine, BUT (im so sorry) they have to be dynamic and unique as there are different products as well where you can choose from different sizes f.e (150 Gramm), (200)

As you can see on this site: https://goo.gl/K5Om7a 

Every of these products has a option of the "Gramms". All differentsizes have different ingredients. Thats why it won't work out, if it only searches for "150 Gramm" and replaces the tooltip. The ingredients (Zutaten) are saved, for each product, in its own variable, called "zutaten" in the back end.

Is there a way too include this variable?

Comment: Can you please let me know where is this "zutaten" variable saved? Is it in product variations? You will have to fetch it for each option and store it somewhere in the HTML and then update the tooltip according to it. Let me know where it is store and as what so I can help you further.

Comment: I've created an attribute in the backend of magento with the attribute code "zutaten". It also part of the attributset for the configurable products and yes it is saved in the product variations

Comment: You will need to get all simple products contained in the configurable product in the template and print out their zutaten attribute in a hidden div. For example: 150 gramm has id=32 the div ID would be <div id="zutate_32">Here goes the zutate content for the 150 Gramm</div> then <div id="zutate_31">Here goes the zutate content for the 200 Gramm</div> and update your javascript to get the selected value, if it's 32, get the HTML from the div with id="zutate_32" and so on.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the forward - but how do you I get the ID from the current selected product? And how to I've to adjust the javascript to make it work with a div container instead of a static text? Can I execute PHP into javascript?